# Infinite loop when trying to login using Servlet Filter in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

I am trying to create a login application using JSF and servlet filter, but when user logs in nothing happens. It redirects to login page again.

Here is the project directory:
[image]

Here is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>javaeetutorial.guessnumber.filters.LoggedInFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- Set the login filter to secure all the pages in the /secured/* path of the application  -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>greeting.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is LoggedInFilter.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaeetutorial.guessnumber.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javaeetutorial.guessnumber.TestBean;

/**
 *
 * @author salih
 */
public class LoggedInFilter implements Filter {

    FilterConfig fc;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        fc = filterConfig;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Enumeration<String> t = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttributeNames();

        while(t.hasMoreElements()) { System.out.println(t.nextElement().toString());}
        TestBean loginBean = (TestBean) ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("testBean");

        // For the first application request there is no loginBean in the session so user needs to log in
        // For other requests loginBean is present but we need to check if user has logged in successfully
        if (loginBean == null || !loginBean.isLoggedIn()) {
            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/login.xhtml");
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Here is TestBean.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaeetutorial.guessnumber;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author salih
 */
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private boolean loggedIn;
    private String username;
    private String password;


    private NavigationBean navigationBean = new NavigationBean();

    private static final String[] users = {"anna:qazwsx", "kate:123456"};

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }

    public String doLogin() {
        // Get every user from our sample database :)
        for (String user : users) {
            String dbUsername = user.split(":")[0];
            String dbPassword = user.split(":")[1];

            // Successful login
            if (dbUsername.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password)) {
                loggedIn = true;
                return navigationBean.redirectToWelcome();
            }
        }

        // Set login ERROR
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Login error!", "ERROR MSG");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        // To to login page
        return navigationBean.toLogin();

    }
}
```

Here is login.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"htth://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"     
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Login form</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>Login here</h3>
        <h:form id="login-form">
           <h:outputText value="username:"/>
           <h:inputText value="#{testBean.username}" id="username"/>
           <br/>
           <h:outputText value="password:"/>
           <h:inputSecret value="#{testBean.password}" id="password"/>
           <br/>
           <h:commandButton id="button" value="Login" action="#{testBean.doLogin}"/>
           <br/>
           <h:commandLink action="#{navigationBean.redirectToInfo}" value="Info page"/>
           <br/>
           <h:messages />
           <br/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like your filter is applied to EVERYTHING.  Shouldn't it exclude the login page?

Comment: No only the pages under secured/

Comment: Sorry, the way the code was parsing, it looked like all the filter mappings were commented out as they were all gray-text.  Can you put a break after getting your `LoginBean` and see if it's always `null`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `LoggedInFilter.doFilter()` method? is the bean set correctly?

Comment: @L-Ray ı tried, it gives a null pointer exception when i added the line 
System.out.println(loginBean);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing JSF managed beans / concepts with CDI managed beans.

First off you neglected to specify your container but I will write one answer for plain servlet container and one for a CDI enabled java application server such as TomEE / Wildfly / Glassfish.

Use `@Named` and `@SessionScoped` but make sure you have the correct @SessionScoped. javax.enterprise.context is the package name. If you use the SessionScoped from JSF the bean will be dependent scoped and that's wrong.

Now remove the filter and do a quick test with a test page. Set a field with `<h:inputText />` and `<h:commandButton>` (both in a `<h:form>`). Make sure the value is still there after F5 and thus sucessfully `@SessionScoped.`

If it does not work makes sure you are using CDI 1.1 or that you have beans.xml present accordingly to docs.

Lastly use

```
@Inject
private TestBean testBean;
```

Or if you have a plain container like Tomcat or Jetty you need to use Deltaspike Core and then:  `TestBean testBean = BeanProvider.getContextualReference(TestBean.class, false);`

good luck

Comment: I changed all 'ManagedBean' to 'Named', and imported the right @SessionScoped library. Session scoped works great, when i press f5 i can see the same values but i still can't login and go to a secured page.

Comment: Now it works, the problem was that i didn't know how to use inject in filter class, now it works fine. thanks